# How to reduce the size of space between gridview items of gridview.builder in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, cross-platform

I made a gridview using `GridView.builder` in Flutter. I made `crossAxisSpacing` and `mainAxisSpacing` as 0. Still, I am getting huge gaps between the items and on the front of gridview. Check the images for exact idea about the spaces.

Image 1 ->

[image: Spaces between items]

Image 2->

[image: Space between first item and starting of gridview]

Here is my code -

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_getx/colors.dart' as color;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List info=[];

  _initData() {
    DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/info.json").then((value) {
      info=json.decode(value);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _initData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: color.AppColor.homePageBackground,
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Training',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.07,
                    color: color.AppColor.homePageTitle,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05,
                  color: color.AppColor.homePageIcons,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.01,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05,
                  color: color.AppColor.homePageIcons,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.015,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05,
                  color: color.AppColor.homePageIcons,
                ),

              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.03,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Your Program',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.04,
                    color: color.AppColor.homePageSubtitle,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                Text(
                  'Details',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.04,
                    color: color.AppColor.homePageDetail,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.008,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05,
                  color: color.AppColor.homePageIcons,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.025,
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.47,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  colors: [
                    color.AppColor.gradientFirst.withOpacity(0.8),
                    color.AppColor.gradientSecond.withOpacity(0.9),
                  ]
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(80),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    offset: Offset(5, 10),
                    blurRadius: 20,
                    color: color.AppColor.gradientSecond.withOpacity(0.2),
                  )
                 ]
                ),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 21, right: 20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Next Workout',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.035,
                        color: color.AppColor.homePageContainerTextSmall,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.015,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Legs Toning',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.053,
                        color: color.AppColor.homePageContainerTextSmall,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.015,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'and Glutes Workout',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.053,
                        color: color.AppColor.homePageContainerTextSmall,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.06,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.timer,
                              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05,
                              color: color.AppColor.homePageContainerTextSmall,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.02,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '60 sec',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.035,
                                color: color.AppColor.homePageContainerTextSmall,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: Container()),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: color.AppColor.gradientFirst,
                                blurRadius: 10,
                                offset: Offset(4, 8),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.play_circle_fill,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.12,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.01,
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.43,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 120,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(
                            "assets/card.jpg",
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 30,
                            offset: Offset(8, 10),
                            color: color.AppColor.gradientSecond.withOpacity(0.4),
                          ),
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 10,
                            offset: Offset(-1, -5),
                            color: color.AppColor.gradientSecond.withOpacity(0.4),
                          ),
                        ]
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5, left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.077),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          //color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(
                              "assets/figure.png",
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      height: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.36, top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.115),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "You are doing great",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: color.AppColor.homePageDetail
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.03,
                          ),
                          RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text: "Keep it up\n",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.038,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: color.AppColor.homePagePlanColor,
                              ),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: "stick to your plan"
                                ),
                              ]
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Area of focus",
                  //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: color.AppColor.homePageTitle,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: OverflowBox(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: info.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                    return Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4,
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  info[i]["img"],
                                ),
                              ),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 3,
                                  offset: Offset(5, 5),
                                  color: color.AppColor.gradientSecond.withOpacity(0.1),
                                ),
                              ]
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: Text(
                                  info[i]["title"],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05,
                                    color: color.AppColor.homePageDetail,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**You may start checking from line 317 for this problem**

**EDIT**: I was able to remove some of the top space using `MediaQuery.removePadding` and setting `removeTop` as true, but still some space is over there.

Comment: `padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),` inside your GridView children maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Remove your row which has only 1 child:

```dart
GridView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: info.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
  ),
  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(
                info[i]["img"]!,
              ),
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                blurRadius: 3,
                offset: Offset(5, 5),
              ),
            ]),
        child: Center(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text(
              info[i]["title"]!,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Don't ask me why though :D

Comment: Bruh, I totally forgot that. That solved one problem. But, how could I reduce the spacing between them? And BTW, still some space is left on the top

Comment: As @Tanguy pointed out, the spacing in-between is due to the padding you use `padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0)` (the first child in your `GridView`)

Answer (score 0):

for child items spacing in Gridview, always use mainAxisSpacing & crossAxisSpacing:

```
GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: info.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                  ),
```